# Error when trying to input date using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match

I have some VBA code to insert an index match function into a table to lookup date values. If a date value can't be found i.e function returns error I want to insert a default date in place of the error.

Initially I tried:

```
Selection.FormulaArray = _
    "=IFERROR(INDEX(PSE_Data[#All],MATCH(RC6,'PSE Data'!C[-11],0),17),""01/01/2020""))"
```

However, this is entering the date as text, rather than date format. So I tried:

```
Dim errordate As Date
    errordate = DateValue("Jan 01, 2020")    
Selection.FormulaArray = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(PSE_Data[#All],MATCH(RC6,'PSE Data'!C[-2],0),17),""errordate""))"
```

However I then get a 1004 runtime error.

Any help on how to resolve would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use `Date(2020,1,1)` instead of `""01/01/2020""`.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen I used `Selection.FormulaArray = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(PSE_Data[#All],MATCH(RC6,'PSE Data'!C[-11],0),17),Date(2020,1,1)))" `  

But I still get an error reading: **Unable to set the FormulaArray property of the Range class.**

Comment: @BigBen Ignore me, your date addition worked fine, I'd added an extra bracket by accident when updating the code! Silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed outby @BigBen, using `Date(2020,1,1)` instead of `""01/01/2020""` resolves the issue!